Sets represented by integral quadratic forms
Let $f(x) = x^\intercal A x$ be a positive definite integral quadratic form on $d$ variables. A positive integer $n$ is said to be represented by $f$ if $f(x) = n$ for some $x \in \mathbb Z^d$. A set of positive integers $S$ may be said to be represented by $f$ if $f(x) \in S$ for some $x \in \mathbb Z^d$.
Some infinite sets $S$ are represented by all positive definite integral quadratic forms on sufficiently many variables. This occurs trivially for $S = \mathbb N$ and, more generally, for any cofinite subset $S \subseteq \mathbb N$. By Meyer's theorem, this also occurs for the set of all squares $S = \{n^2 : n \in \mathbb N\}$. However, this does not occur for all infinite $S \subseteq \mathbb N$. For example, the quadratic form of $E_8$ respresents only even integers.
What sets of positive integers are known to be represented by all positive definite integral quadratic forms or by some class of such forms? I am particularly interested to know whether all unimodular positive definite integral quadratic forms on six or more variables represent a power of two.
(The quadratic form $f$ is said to be integral if $A$ has integer coefficients, it is said to be positive definite if $A$ is positive definite, and it is said to be unimodular if $A$ has determinant one.)

check http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/  for examples...  Here is the Leech lattice page http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Leech.html   and here is the Gram matrix  http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Leech.html#GRAM   Quicker:  the minimum http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Leech.html#MINIMAL_NORM

@WillJagy: Thanks a lot for these resources. To clarify, are you saying that this matrix provides a counterexample?

No,  just a place to begin looking. My first impression is that your conjecture is quite likely, for dimension five and above local obstructions vanish; for that sort of thing I like Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. The usual reference for positive unimodular is SPLAG by Conway and Sloane. I also like Lattices and Codes by Ebeling.

Your question can be reformulated in terms of non-vanishing of certain coefficients of theta-series, which probably opens the door to results on modular forms that might be relevant. For instance, for an even lattice the theta-function is a polynomial function of $E_4$ and $E_6$ (E for Eisenstein). (Whether this is useful or not, I don't know.)
